# iOS Ringtone usage tracking

Tags: ios, tracking, ringtone

Is there a way to track ringtone usage with the current iOS api? I am looking to make an application that will allow us to track the usage of specific ringtones.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of doing this with the current public API.

Comment: That is what I thought. Thank you for confirming that!